# Swift loading Parse PFUser information into a view is failing with found nil while unwrapping optional

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Ive waisted too much time on this one. And maybe thats why I can't see the problem.

I'm loading PFUser data from Parse into a view so that it can be edited etc.

This section of my code keeps crashing with the unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value for which I know has a value.

```
func loadUser() {
   // var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    println(currentUser)

    //currentUser = nil

    if currentUser != nil {


        if let userImageView = currentUser?["picture"] as? PFFile {
            userImageView.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if let currentUser = currentUser {

        var userName: AnyObject? = currentUser["username"]

        println(userName)
   //     if let currentUser = currentUser {
            self.nameField.text = userName as! String
   //     }
        }
    }
}
```

both println(currentUser) and println(userName) have values and show on my console.

Comment: Where exactly does is crash?

Comment: let image = UIImage(data:imageData) and self.nameField.text = userName as! String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it seems unlikely, it is possible that your `currentUser` variable is being deallocated from under your feet — why don't you use conditional assignment from the start:

```
if let currentUser = currentUser {

    if let userImageView = currentUser["picture"] as? PFFile {
        userImageView.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    if let image = UIImage(data:imageData) {
                        // do whatever you want to do with your image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if let userName: String = currentUser["username"] as? String {
        println(userName)
        self.nameField.text = userName
    }
}
```

Given where you say that it crashes, it would seem much more likely that your `currentUser` object has a `nil` `userName` property (or one that is not a `String`.

Also, `UIImage(data: NSData)` returns an optional so if you are trying to use it, it may be `nil` (and, depending on the libraries you are using, it might be declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional).

I generally avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals like the plague because of these types of errors — if you are always using conditional assignments rather than checking for nil then attempting to use the variable as an implicitly unwrapped optional then this shouldn't happen.

Comment: That seems to help out the problem.